# Convert local object to pointer, without copying the data?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class *cnList* which stores a flexible number of items. This list must later be converted to a *cnArray* object. The list class already implements a method `cnArray cnList::toArray() const`.

But as you can see, it returns an object, not a reference nor a pointer.  But what I have to do after converting the list to an array, is to store this array for later use in a class member, this means, I need to have a pointer to that *cnArray* object.

Now, the actual problem is, simply using the arrays adress is not an option because it gets freed after the method I'm currently in, ends.

Can I somehow "convert" this object to a pointer and the object isn't freed anymore ?
Sure, I could copy all entries from the object-array to a pointed-array, but thats not what I want, since it's not very efficient.

I am aware of the fact that I could implement a method in *cnList* that returns a pointer to a *cnArray* object, but I'd like to know if there is around this.

Comment: have you checked whether cnList does any reference counting?

Comment: Have you implemented move semantics in cnArray?  Why not just return by value?

Comment: @Jimmy Why should it ? And what does this have to do with the topic ?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Sorry, what method should return what by value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can allocate a new cnArray from the heap, constructed from the return value of `toArray`. If you do it right, [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) will allow the compiler to optimize out the redundant copy:

```
cnArray *p = new cnArray(list.toArray());
```

To see that g++'s RVO will eliminate the copy, see http://ideone.com/loXAT

Comment: Wow. Actually it's so simple and obvious, thank you. Works just fine !

Answer (score 0):

Pointers can be deference and used just as normal locals.  The issue is you don't convert an automatic to a heap allocated object you just use the heap object.  I would advise however to use shared_ptr if its possible.

```
cnArray* Ptr = new cnArray();
(*Ptr) = cnList::toArray();
```

Comment: Using this code gives undefined results. The stored data is messed up. Rewriting cnList::toArray() to return a pointer works, so it is not my other code.

Answer (score 0):

In `cnList::toArray()`, you can dynamically allocate a `cnArray* obj`, convert your `cnList` object to `obj` and then return `obj`. Since you're passing the raw (or smart) pointer back, it will not be deallocated when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Ye, I think that's what I meant with implementing a method that returns a pointer instead of an object. This does work indeed very fine, I think I will leave as it is. Was just interested if I couldn't just prevent an object on the heap to be deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

The cnList is being *copied* to a new cnArray. The `cnArray::ToList` function could have been written to accept a reference or pointer to an existing cnArray, but it was not. If you can change the interface you should consider this.

The returned cnArray is a local object that will be destroyed when it goes out of scope, and you seem to understand this. The only choice you have is to make another copy of it into a member variable of your object.

Some C++ compilers will do [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) which prevents a superfluous copy from being made. Instead of assigning the return value to a temporary, assign it directly to the member variable.